# Run two batch files at the same time and wait until both are finished to run the next

Tags: r, shell, multiple-instances

I like to start `script1` and `script2` at the same time and ensure that both are finished before `script3` is executed (Windows Server 2008 R2).

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save %~dp0src/script1.R
R CMD BATCH --no-save %~dp0src/script2.R
R CMD BATCH --no-save %~dp0src/script3.R
```

I have searched the board but could not get it to work.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if it is ok for you to wait for each of first 2 scripts then you can use

```
start /wait command1
start /wait command2
start command3
```

but this will not execute simultaneously commands 1 and 2; if you really need them simultaneously - you have to try with some tricky logic(I would not do) to have command 2 in separate script or even both command 1 too, then check for status there and continue with command 3 only when all states are ok

Comment: Thanks Vairis. Unfortunately, this does not address my question. I do like to run the first two scripts at the same time and then the third once both are executed.

Comment: @Researcher then as I wrote - separate those commands per 3 different files, run first 2 simultaneously do some loop for checking for both to finish and then run 3rd. pseudo code for loop:

`start`
`if cmd1 ok and cmd2 ok goto cmd3`
`goto start`
(hope its clear that there are 3 lines of commands :)